# How to have javascript fill out and submit a form on another webpage

Tags: javascript, html, forms, cordova

I have a website that manages where people are and what they are doing at work and if they need help or not.

I am using phone gap in order to make my application and I was wondering if it is possible to take a button on the phone gap and have javascript fill out a form on my webpage and then submit it so I can then process that data?

The form that I am trying to connect to is. I process this form in python through flask:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id = "stuff">
   <dl>
      <dt>
      <input type=text name=gc>
      <input type=text name=cursquad>
      <input type=text name=trap>
      <input type=text name=scrtkey>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an AJAX post request with jquery, but then you'll need jquery in your phonegap, which might be quite overkill only for this.

Therefor I'd recommend this approach:

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var url = "http://example.com";
  var parameters = "foo=bar&bar=baz"; // Construct you form values like field=value&field2=value2&...

  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parameters.length);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
  xmlhttp.send(parameters);
}
</script>
```

This will POST all the data you put into parameters to the url you give. If you point it to your form page it should work.

If it doesn't, (jquery approach doesn't work out of the box), you might have to add some headers to the receiving page to allow it to receive data from external pages. The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is needed here, where you can provide a list of safe domains. Since your application is not on a domain though, you could add this to your receiving page (Assuming you are running php):

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Try running it without first though, as it opens your form for everyone.

Comment: That is not caused by Javascript, please update your question with the PHP that handles the respononse.

Comment: I don't use php to process the questions I use python

Comment: I am unfamiliar with python, but I suppose it goes wrong there somewhere. Perhaps it would be better to create a new question with the relevant python and javascript codes. See if someone with python knowledge can help you.

Comment: I am using the post as my way to transmit information would it be possible to fake that information with Javascrpit

Comment: You could create a jsfiddle on jsfiddle.net and use jQuery post() to test: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ (add jquery library to the fiddle in the left menu)